# Enterprise Architect: How to show packages with tables on a diagram and relations between tables?

Tags: enterprise-architect

How to show packages with tables on a diagram and relations between tables?

Now I'm using boundaries to group tables. I want do this by sub-diagram.

When I put packages on a diagram I want to see relations between the tables (PK,FK) defined in the packages. When I click on the pasted package I want to see the sub-diagrams.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a package contains a diagram, and you place that package in another diagram, double-clicking that package will open its diagram.

You can select whether to show the contents of packages in a diagram's properties.

However, in a diagram which shows packages A and B you cannot show the relationships between elements in those packages. The only way to show relationships between elements is to place both sets of elements in the diagram.